# How to join by two fields (CriteriaBuilder)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.1

I have an entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`petition`")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Petition extends Auditable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3234225397035713824L;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "petition_selected_school", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "petition_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "school_id",
                    nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    private List<School> selectedSchools;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "petition_basic_school", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "petition_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "school_id",
                    nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    private List<School> fullBasicSchoolList;

}
```

I'd like to build SQL select like this via criteria buildeer

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  p.id
FROM petition p JOIN petition_selected_school s ON p.id = s.petition_id
  LEFT JOIN petition_basic_school b ON p.id = b.petition_id AND s.school_id = b.school_id
WHERE b IS NULL
ORDER BY p."id" ASC
```

I tryied this:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Petition> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Petition.class);
Root root = criteriaQuery.from(Petition.class);
criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
Join join = root.join("selectedSchools");
Join join2 = root.join("fullBasicSchoolList", JoinType.LEFT,);
Predicate p = builder.equal(join2.get("school"),join.get("school"));
finalPredicateList.add(p);
criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.where(builder.and(finalPredicateList.toArray(new Predicate[finalPredicateList.size()])));
```

but there was generated sql like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  petition0_.id AS col_0_0_
FROM "petition" petition0_ INNER JOIN petition_selected_school selectedsc1_ ON petition0_.id = selectedsc1_.petition_id
  INNER JOIN "school" school2_ ON selectedsc1_.school_id = school2_.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN petition_basic_school fullbasics3_ ON petition0_.id = fullbasics3_.petition_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "school" school4_ ON fullbasics3_.school_id = school4_.id
WHERE petition0_.id = 245 AND school4_.school = school2_.school
```

Main question is "how to join not only by one parameter"?

```
p.id = b.petition_id AND s.school_id = b.school_id
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of JPA are you using?

In JPA 2.1 you can join by two fields as long as one is the one that determines the relationship in the following way:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Petition> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Petition.class);
Root root = criteriaQuery.from(Petition.class);
criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
Join join = root.join("selectedSchools");
//FIRST CONDITION (BY ID)
Join join2 = root.join("fullBasicSchoolList", JoinType.LEFT,);
//NEW
join2.on([SECOND_CONDITION])
[...]
```